# AJAX .load() function will not get any content

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I'm pretty new to JQuery/AJAX and am trying to use a simple 'load' function. For whatever reason, when I call the function on an element in my HTML code, it doesn't seem to be responding. Not receiving any errors so unsure what is causing the problem.

JQuery/AJAX (C:\Uni\3rd year\CITS3403\JQueryAJAX\jqueryhtm.html):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#toimport").load("sometext.txt");
        })
```

HTML (C:\Uni\3rd year\CITS3403\JQueryAJAX\jqueryhtm.html):

```
<div id = "toimport">

        </div>
```

Plain Text File (C:\Uni\3rd year\CITS3403\JQueryAJAX\sometext.txt):

```
<h1>here is some text</h1>
```

I'd expect this to result in the "sometext.txt" contents being loaded into the "toimport" div, however I am getting no results when I run it.

Comment: *"Not receiving any errors"* - That's pretty unlikely.  Do you know where to look for errors?

Comment: As in I'm not seeing any in my editor (Visual Studio)

Comment: When you run this in a web browser, open your browser's debugging tools and look at the console output.  You're only looking for *design time* errors.  The code is syntactically correct and produces no design time errors.  However, if it's not working when you execute the code then you need to look for run time errors.

Comment: Yep. Returned this: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running this as a file. Opening the file directly in a browser, it won't work. You need to be running a webserver for ajax to work

Comment: Ok I have just been running this through my browser. How do I run a webserver?

Comment: If you're familiar with node.

Look into https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server
Install it, run the command in the directory http-server . and open the url it suggests in the browser. The easiest way to run a web server.
Or look into install lamp stack